# per day basis partition in oracle with column datatype number

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, database-administration

I have a requirement where i need to create partition of a table per day basis as load is very high in oracle 11g.
    I have checked many blogs where i found we can do it by use of 'NUMTODSINTERVAL' function, but i have a challenges like in the table there is no date column and i need to create partition on a number column which is behaving like a date in the table.

```
cobdate
---------
20141205
```

i thought of to implement as below :

```
partition by range(cobdate)
interval(1)
```

but it ll create problem after few days as it will not create new partition while it reach to the next month and all data will go to some sys define partition afterward .

can we convert `number` to `date` and use it in the partitioning column with `NUMTODSINTERVAL` function ?  which is currently in my mind as a solution..?    please suggest

Comment: can you use pseudocolumn ora_rowscn as your timestamp and SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP to convert the value to a date. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm  note the tables impacted must have DEPENDENCIES enabled if you want row level timestamps; otherwise records will be managed at a block level. `Select Table_name, dependencies from all_tables where table_name = 'yourtable'` if value is DISABLED then you have block level locking enabled; and this may not result in what you're  after

Comment: What does "all data will go to some sys defined partition afterward" mean and why is that a problem?  If you are using interval partitioning, Oracle will automatically create system-named partitions whenever a new value is encountered.  It sounds like you're describing the expected behavior of interval partitioning.  Now, you may have problems with interval partitioning on a numeric column that is very sparse like this (particularly if you have data from before 2000) but that doesn't seem to be the issue you're having.

Comment: @JustinCave you are correct!! i got it now oracle will create new system-named partitions whenever a new value is encountered.Thank you .but i am wondering now how about if i want to delete partition which is less then 3 days,to achieve this i think we need to describe the expected behavior ?, or is there any other way around ?

No i don't have data from before 2000
i have data only after 20140101.    Thanks

Comment: @xQbert Thanks for the comment. However ORA_ROWSCN and SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP  is not absolutely precise, because Oracle tracks SCNs by transaction committed for the block in which the row resides and SCN immediate change to next SCN when ever there is a update in the row. correct me if i am wrong. Thanks

Comment: @sabyasachikar You're correct about block locking by default, which is why I mentioned looking at dependencies. in all_tables to see if it is enabled on the table.  If dependencies are enabled block level locking no longer applies and each row and each update would obtain it's own unique ORA_ROWSCN. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm for more info or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3406149/rowdependencies-overhead-in-oracle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally concluded with a answer which is relevant to this question,where i have implemented it as below :

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_PART
(
  COBDATE                  NUMBER(9)    
)

PARTITION BY RANGE (COBDATE)
SUBPARTITION BY RANGE (COBDATE)
(  
  PARTITION P_2014 VALUES LESS THAN (20150101)
         ( SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_01 VALUES LESS THAN (20140102)      TABLESPACE TBS_NAME,
           SUBPARTITION P_2014_JAN_02 VALUES LESS THAN (20140103)      TABLESPACE TBS_NAME,
           .
           .
           .
           SUBPARTITION P_2014_DEC_31 VALUES LESS THAN (20150101)      TABLESPACE TBS_NAME)

 )
NOCACHE            
PARALLEL        
MONITORING;
```

and i have automate it in a UNIX shell script which ll create partition automatically afterword (for year :2015,2016..).
Happy Learning :)